# Load Custom form using Suitescript 2.0

Tags: forms, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

There is a requirement to load custom form and access the form details from the CustomForm record and display on PDF generating via Suitescript. Unable to do it via SuiteScript 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to the following:

```
    require(['N/render','N/record'],
    function(render, record) {
        function loadForms(){
            var formRec = record.load({type: 'custform', id: formId});
            var formType = formRec.getValue({fieldId: 'formtypename'});
        }
    }
    loadForms();
});
```

Tested in NetSuite-Debugguer

Comment: This appears not to be working.

Comment: Throws a RCRD_DSNT_EXIST error.